# fatal: could not create work tree dir 'scrumwala.git.': Permission denied

Tags: linux, github, clone

I am trying to clone project from github

i tried

```
git clone https://github.com/modestkdr/scrumwala.git.
```

but when i got error

> fatal: could not create work tree dir 'scrumwala.git.': Permission
>   denied

then i tried

```
sudo chown -R root /var/www
```

but same error exist.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git clone` is done with your current (local Linux) account, not `root`.
So a `sudo chown -R root` would not change anything.

Check the rights associated with your current path, and make sure you (your current account) has the right to write in it.

Comment: @Shanukk no: current account used for your local Linux session.

Answer (score -1):

You just insert the sudo command to run

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/modestkdr/scrumwala.git
```

if there's any problem, don't hesitate to notify me by way of a comment.

Comment: Don't do that https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey#should-the-sudo-command-be-used-with-git